# "Content-type" for uploading jars files using Web HDFS REST client

Tags: hadoop, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, webhdfs

I am using Web HDFS REST client, I am able to upload `.xml` & `.q` files.

Useful part of code -

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(urlString);
httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
```

I am getting issue while uploading `.jar`. Uploaded file is corrupted.

What should I set in "Content-type" and ""Accept"" for uploading jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(urlString);
httpPut.setEntity(new StringEntity(readFile(fileName)));
httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "binary/octet-stream");
httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "binary/octet-stream");
```

Use **`binary/octet-stream`** instead of  **`application/xml`**.